# convert string to float: '998 CC'

Tags: python-3.x

I ran the code below:

```
if isinstance(Engine, str):
        return float(Engine.replace('cc', ''))
    else:
        return np.nan
```

I got the error below; because there is space between 988 and CC

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '998 CC'
```

How should I convert string to float: '998 CC' to 998 without space and CC

Comment: Hi, are you familiar with [capitalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization)?

Comment: Hi, was your question answered? If so, could you please accept the correct answer? If not, what can be clarified? (See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).)

Comment: Question was answered. Thank you.

Comment: If your question has been answered, you should accept the correct answer with the checkmark beside it. This helps future users who have similar concerns.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `replace` call doesn't actually find `'CC'`, because you told it to look for `'cc'`. Programs typically treat [capital and lowercase variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization) of text differently.

Looking for `'CC'` instead:

```
if isinstance(Engine, str):
        return float(Engine.replace('CC', ''))
    else:
        return np.nan
```

If you expect to see both `'CC'` and `'cc'`, you can do this:

```
if isinstance(Engine, str):
        return float(Engine.lower().replace('cc', ''))
    else:
        return np.nan
```